# Spring JPA: How to check if Entity belongs to current JPA transaction?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I need the ability to check if Entity belongs to the current ongoing transaction.  I have a JPA entity cache as a thread-local cache.  Almost always when there is single @Transaction there is no issue when a same thread calls multiple times to save on service and NOT nested @Trasaction(Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) (meaning when you have nested transactions) on same thread it does not work.   Is there any way to check if JPA Entity ( MyExpesiveEntity) belongs to the current ongoing transaction?

```
        ThreadLocal<Map<Long,MyExpesiveEntity>> cache = new ThreadLocal<Map<Long,MyExpesiveEntity>>()
        @Entity('MyExpesiveEntity')
        class MyExpesiveEntity{
        }

        @Transaction 
        save(DTO save){
            MyExpesiveEntity entity = cache.get(dto.getID());
            if(entity == null){
                  entity = myExpesiveRespository.findById(dto.getID());
                  cache.get().put(entity.getID(),entity);
             }

             entity.setXXX(dto.getXXX()) 
             // THIS always works but Sometime when the caller is using
             // Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW. 
             // It does not work when you have nested transactions.It throws duplicated id.
             myExpesiveRespository.saveAndFlush(entity);
        }
```

Comment: From look of you code the entity is always existing(cache or datastore), is that assumption correct?

Comment: Yes, Entity Always exits that is a correct assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Hibernate specific, but yes, this is possible

```
public boolean containsEntity(EntityManager em, Class<?> entityClass, Object id) {
    SessionImplementor session = em.unwrap(SessionImplementor.class);
    EntityKey entityKey = session.generateEntityKey((Serializable) id, session.getFactory().getEntityPersister(entityClass.getName()));
    PersistenceContext pc = session.getPersistenceContext();
    return pc.getEntity(entityKey) != null || pc.getProxy(entityKey) != null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you I think this is working as I tested.  Thank for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. I would appreciate if you mark my answer as correct :)

Answer (score 1):

Since the entity is always existing you could simply update based on the ID. See [`Modifying`](http://Then%20rather%20than%20saving,%20you%20could%20write%20update%20method%20on%20the%20repository.%20See%20[%60@modifying%60](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/Modifying.html))

```
@Modifying
@Query("update MyExpesiveEntity expEnt set expEnt.xxxx = ?1 where expEnt.id = ?2")
void setXxxById(String xxxx, Integer id);
```

Comment: Thanks for the info but my Entity is nested and complex.  @Mofiying is not an option.